# assert/require vs let the function fail

Tags: solidity

```
contract Example { 
  address[] addresses;

  function getAddress(uint index) external view returns (address){
      return addresses[index];
  }

  function getAddress1(uint index) external view returns (address) {
      require(index < addresses.length);
      return addresses[index];
  }
 }
```

Both the function will fail if I will try accessing an element which doesn't exist.

Is there a difference in the 2 functions? 
In general should I prefer `require` to verify all the conditions or let the function fail like `getAddress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a difference in the 2 functions?

- `getAddress` raises **assert-style exception**
- `getAddress1` raises **require-style exception**

I will link below the page in solidity docs where you can find all situations which invoke this exceptions.

### [Error handling: Assert, Require, Revert and Exceptions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.19/control-structures.html?#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)

> 1. If you access an array at a too large or negative index (i.e. x[i] where i >= x.length or i < 0).
>
>    ...
> 2. If you call a function via a message call but it does not finish
>      properly (i.e. it runs out of gas, has no matching function, or throws
>      an exception itself)

- assert-style exception will use all the gas up to `gasLimit` (e.g. 300000 gas)
- require-style exception will just take fee for computations and revert to initial state (23078 gas)

---

> In general should I prefer require to verify all the conditions or let
>   the function fail like getAddress?

Best practice is to check conditions with require in the beginning of the function or by using modifier.